# Joining two tables on Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to join two tables on my query.

Database structure

```
Products
    .id
    .image
    .category_id (points to categories.id)

Categories
    .id
    .category_name
    .category_directory_name
```

Images are under `category_directory_name` directory, so I need to set a relation between these two tables so I can get `category_directory_name` of each `product`.

Something like;

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('uploads/categories/' . $v->category_directory_name . '/' . $v->image') }}">
```

How can I do it?

Ps. My table and column namings are local, so I'm not using builtin features of Laravel and Eloquent. I want to define table and column names myself.

Comment: So you're trying to build relationships, using Eloquent, but not using the built-in mechanisms of Eloquent? I'm not sure what you mean by your names being "local" ?

Comment: For example, Eloquent model can be named as "Product", and it will point to "Products" table automatically. My table and column named are written in a different language, so relying on builtin features of Eloquent will not work.

Comment: Interesting - can you give a concrete example here? Does another language not work because of a utf8 encoding issue?

Comment: Well, you should read Laravel's documentation a bit. It's not about encoding, it's about the language. Product, in plural form, is Products. Laravel is smart enough to understand plural form in English so it may point Products table without you defining one. Laravel doesn't know plural form of model name in my native language. "Urun" model points to "Urunler" table, and I have to define it manually by doing "protected $table = 'urunler';" in my "Urun" model to make Laravel aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Product model you should do

```
public function category() {

    return $this->belongsTo('Category');

}
```

In your controller:

```
public function index() {

    $product = Product::find(1);

    return View::make('yourViewName')->with('product', $product);

}
```

In your view:

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('uploads/categories/' . $product->category->category_directory_name . '/' . $product->image') }}">
```

Comment: This *should* be the answer, but I'm confused on the language "constraint" in the comments of the OP.

Comment: @fideloper: Yes, it is. I had 3 minutes before I could select this as the correct answer. AntonioCarlosRiberio: Thanks alot!